# How to customize ID value of the items displayed in?

Tags: android-listview, android-adapterview

I have multiple items in RecyclerView element, and the IDs of those items are generated automatically.
For some reason, I need to set specific id values instead of automatically generated ones.
My question is it possible to set specific ID values on items in the RecyclerView element.

Is it possible to set specific ID values on items in the RecyclerView element?

Comment: You have a backing array in which each array element represents one item in the `RecyclerView`, correct? Call it `Array<Thing>`. So why not just store this information in the `Thing` class?

Comment: The way the RecyclerView works is it has a handful of ViewHolder objects that it reuses (recycles) to display the visible items in the list. So you might have 200 items, but only 11 actual ViewHolder `View`s - and depending on what's happening with the data, an item in your list might end up displaying in different `ViewHolder` objects over the lifetime of the view. So I guess the question is, why do you want to control the IDs of those ViewHolders? (I assume that's what you mean.) That's an internal detail, and not a very useful thing to use from the outside. There's probably a better way

Comment: @GavinWright thanks for the post.
Can you please attach a link with some explanation of the solution?
I am new in this field.

Comment: @cactustictacs, I need it for QA purpose

Comment: @Michael You'll have to explain more about your specific implementation. Where are you getting the data for the `RecyclerView`? How is the data stored?

Comment: @Michael if you tell us what general problem you're trying to solve, you might get some helpful ideas. If you want to set the ID on the layout view you provide in `onCreateViewHolder`, you can do that with `setId` on the `View`. But if you're talking about the results of `getItemId()` on the `ViewHolder` itself, your `Adapter` needs to override `hasStableIds()` to return *true* and override `getItemId(position)` to return an ID for that item which doesn't depend on its position in the list. But that function returns `NO_ID` by default so I'm not sure what "automatically generated" IDs you mean